# UITextView variable, allow to set text using special method only?

Tags: ios, resize, uitextfield, private-methods, public-members

I have a `UITextField` property inside a `UIViewController` class. I want to allow to set its text using a special method in view controller only. The goal is to move other view controller's elements according to a size of a text inside the text field.

Text field has editing option disabled so it can be setted in code only.

Way 1:

Subclass a `UITextField`. Looks too extra because I need to set the elements which doesn't belong to this text field. So I need to use a delegate (and as I understand it will be my own delegate only) etc.

Way 2:

Make text field property private. It is my current solution but I don't like that it is fully private.

Can anybody advice a better solution?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you can you explain more clearly?

Comment: How about making the `UITextView` an instance variable not a property. And access it via methods or only set the text via methods. Anyway, fully private is not available in objective-c :D

Comment: to danypata, it is almost the same as my way #2. And even worse.
to Tendulkar, ideally I want to make `textView.text` default setter private for all except of one method. And this method belongs to a view controller, not `UITextView`.